# Power Apps : Is there any way to again user permission to connect data source again

Tags: powerapp

I have created a Power app but one of the user mistakenly switch account while allowing the app. Is there any way to again ask user with the popup to allow permissions so user can switch to actual user ?

[image]

Comment: You tried opening the application in incognito/guest window & login with correct user account?

Comment: Yes I tried signing out, Clear history  used incognito

Comment: Ask user to try removing respective connection from "Connections" section. [Follow this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Forcing-consent-pop-up-again/m-p/1371111/highlight/true#M356855) - let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes it worked :) , please add your answer so I can marked as Accepted Answer

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I have added the same as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask user to try removing respective connection from "Connections" section.

Follow the steps:

1. Go to https://make.powerapps.com
2. From the left menu bar, click **Dataverse** and then select **Connections**
3. Click ellipses next to respective connection then click Delete
4. Clear all browser cache and cookies, close browser, re-open browser and sign in again.
5. Open the app again - it should show the popup again

**Reference**: [Forcing consent pop up again](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Forcing-consent-pop-up-again/m-p/1371111/highlight/true#M356855)